# Asignar valores a una columna según valores en otra columna

Tags: r

Necesito asignar en la columna a de un *dataframe* el valor `b` cada vez que sea verdadera una condición, ¿hay alguna forma de no tener que duplicar el filtro en ambos lados de la ecuación?

Por ejemplo, para la condición `b > a`:

```
f <- f(x,y) { x < y} 
df$a[f(df[,c("a","b")])] <- df$b[f(df[,c("a","b")])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongamos el dataframe df tiene 2 columnas: 'a' y 'b'. Quieres asignar el valor de la columna 'b' a la columna 'a' si el valor de 'b' es mayor que el valor de 'a'.

```
df[df$a < df$b,1] <- df$b
```

Answer (score 1):

La función que pusiste no anda, creo que la función que quisiste definir es

```
f <- function(x){x$a < x$b}
```

Si se lo aplico a este `dataframe` que defino a continuación, obtengo el resultado que querés:

```
library(tibble)
(df <- data_frame(a = 1:5, b = 3))

# A tibble: 5 × 2
      a     b
  <int> <dbl>
1     1     3
2     2     3
3     3     3
4     4     3
5     5     3

(df$a[f(df[,c("a","b")])] <- df$b[f(df[,c("a","b")])])

# A tibble: 5 × 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     3
2     3     3
3     3     3
4     4     3
5     5     3
```

Usando la función `ifelse` y el paquete `dplyr` se puede hacer sin necesidad de definir funciones:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(a = ifelse(a < b, b, a))
```